# Mutate new column based on different datasets

Tags: r, match, dplyr

Example I have three datasets: **df1_mean** (means for each variable based on df1), **df1_sd** (sd for each variable based on df1) and **df2** (values for df2).

**df1_mean:**

```
  A_mean B_mean C_mean D_mean E_mean
1     10     15     12     25     29
```

**df1_sd:**

```
  A_sd B_sd C_sd D_sd E_sd
1    3    2    5    4    2
```

**df2:**

```
  A  B  C  D  E
1 20 32 12 14 22
2 21 35 14 52 13
3 25 23 21 32 35
4 23 12 11 52 21
5 20 53 43 12 64
6 30 12 23 53 31
```

Ideally, I would like to match the `*_mean` and `*_sd` from **df1** for each variable (i.e. A, B, C, D, E respectively) in **df2**, then `mutate()` a new column based on formula, and output new columns for each .

For each variable, the final outcome should look like:

`df2$A_output = (df2$A - df1$A_mean) / df1$A_sd`

Would anyone know if theres's a way to use data from different datasets to `mutate()` new columns? Or what would be the easiest way to automate this rather than manually using `A_output = (A-10)/3, B_output = (B-15)/2, ...`? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some base R options:

- Using `rep`

```
dfout <- (df2 - df1_mean[rep(1,nrow(df2)),])/df1_sd[rep(1,nrow(df2)),]
```

- Using `sweep`

```
dfout <- sweep(sweep(df2,2,unlist(df1_mean)),2,unlist(df1_sd),FUN = `/`)
```

---

Both will give

```
> dfout
         A    B    C     D    E
1 3.333333  8.5  0.0 -2.75 -3.5
2 3.666667 10.0  0.4  6.75 -8.0
3 5.000000  4.0  1.8  1.75  3.0
4 4.333333 -1.5 -0.2  6.75 -4.0
5 3.333333 19.0  6.2 -3.25 17.5
6 6.666667 -1.5  2.2  7.00  1.0
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1_mean)
structure(list(A_mean = 10L, B_mean = 15L, C_mean = 12L, D_mean = 25L,
    E_mean = 29L), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")

> dput(df1_sd)
structure(list(A_sd = 3L, B_sd = 2L, C_sd = 5L, D_sd = 4L, E_sd = 2L), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")

> dput(df2)
structure(list(A = c(20L, 21L, 25L, 23L, 20L, 30L), B = c(32L,
35L, 23L, 12L, 53L, 12L), C = c(12L, 14L, 21L, 11L, 43L, 23L),
    D = c(14L, 52L, 32L, 52L, 12L, 53L), E = c(22L, 13L, 35L, 
    21L, 64L, 31L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
as.data.frame(Map(function(x, mu, sig) (x - mu) / sig, df2, df1_mean, df1_sd))
```

Output

```
         A    B    C     D    E
1 3.333333  8.5  0.0 -2.75 -3.5
2 3.666667 10.0  0.4  6.75 -8.0
3 5.000000  4.0  1.8  1.75  3.0
4 4.333333 -1.5 -0.2  6.75 -4.0
5 3.333333 19.0  6.2 -3.25 17.5
6 6.666667 -1.5  2.2  7.00  1.0
```

Comment: As a person whose code leans heavily tidyverse, I really appreciate seeing a single line of base code that is so much more efficient and straightforward than all the pipes I would have done

Comment: @camille Moving problems in and out of the tidyverse long-data paradigm takes work. If `df2` were a already in long format with columns var and value, and `df1` was a singe data frame with 3 columns (var, mean, sd), and the desired result was tidy too, this would be a simple 2 lines of `dplyr` (or 2 lines of `base`, just a `merge` and a `transform`). Similarly, `df1` was a matrix and `df2_mean` and `df2_sd` were vectors, not data frames, my `base` answer would be simpler. This answer meets the problem nicely where it's at, but the problem is in a bit of an unfortunate starting place IMHO.

Comment: (And not really @ you so much as I appreciated your comment and it sparked some thoughts for me... I've seen enough of your contributions on here to know you're no slouch :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to use vectorized math and some transposes to make recycling work:

```
t( (t(df2) - unlist(df1_mean)) / unlist(df1_sd) )
#          A    B    C     D    E
# 1 3.333333  8.5  0.0 -2.75 -3.5
# 2 3.666667 10.0  0.4  6.75 -8.0
# 3 5.000000  4.0  1.8  1.75  3.0
# 4 4.333333 -1.5 -0.2  6.75 -4.0
# 5 3.333333 19.0  6.2 -3.25 17.5
# 6 6.666667 -1.5  2.2  7.00  1.0
```

It relies on the columns of the three data frames being in corresponding order. As long as that holds true, it should be very efficient.

Comment: Maybe use `unlist(..., FALSE, FALSE)` for greater efficiency?

Comment: Doubtful the microseocnds saved would matter, but a good comment for anyone interested in hyperefficiency. I'll keep it without just to keep the code a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
Output <- df2 %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  left_join(df1_mean %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
              separate(name,c('name','Var'),sep='_') %>%
              rename(Mean=value) %>% select(-Var)
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    df1_sd %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
      separate(name,c('name','Var'),sep='_') %>%
      rename(SD=value) %>% select(-Var)
  ) %>% mutate(Val=(value-Mean)/SD) %>% select(-c(value,Mean,SD)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=Val) %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
      A     B     C     D     E
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  3.33   8.5   0   -2.75  -3.5
2  3.67  10     0.4  6.75  -8  
3  5      4     1.8  1.75   3  
4  4.33  -1.5  -0.2  6.75  -4  
5  3.33  19     6.2 -3.25  17.5
6  6.67  -1.5   2.2  7      1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df1_mean <- structure(list(A_mean = 10L, B_mean = 15L, C_mean = 12L, D_mean = 25L,E_mean = 29L), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")

#Data 2
df1_sd <-structure(list(A_sd = 3L, B_sd = 2L, C_sd = 5L, D_sd = 4L, E_sd = 2L), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")

#Data 3
df2 <- structure(list(A = c(20L, 21L, 25L, 23L, 20L, 30L), B = c(32L, 
35L, 23L, 12L, 53L, 12L), C = c(12L, 14L, 21L, 11L, 43L, 23L), 
    D = c(14L, 52L, 32L, 52L, 12L, 53L), E = c(22L, 13L, 35L, 
    21L, 64L, 31L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: I tried out something similar, but you have a few spots where you can drop additional functions by making use of arguments within the `pivot` functions. No need to call `separate` or `rename` if you set the `names_pattern` argument and use the `".value"` shortcut

Comment: @Duck Thanks! I tried this for the test data and it runs successfully. I encountered an error when trying with my dataset though, `Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows [1].Joining, by = "name"`, trying to fix it now.

Comment: @smicaela Hi micaela. Maybe in your data the suffixes in other dataframes are different. You can check with `names()` and see if there is other separator different to `_`